# Are there any sources which talk about the experience of attending a 15th/16th century fencing school?

Tags: middle-ages, cultural-history, 15th-century

I'm interested to know of any material which describes the experience of being a student at a medieval period fencing school e.g. once which may have been run by a Master teaching in the Lichtenauer longsword tradition or other similar period weapons.